# Pseudo-French words in German

Tags: french, false-friends

In her review of Vanderperren, Dictionnaire des faux amis/Wörterbuch der faux amis. Allemand-francais/Deutch-Französisch, Paris, 1994, published in Romanistiches Jahrbuch, vol. 46, issue 1, the reviewer Claudia Polzin mentions on p. 207

> "französierende(n) Bildungen", d.h. "bizarre(n) Wörter(n) deutscher
>   Prägung, die wie französische Wörter aussehen, aber keine sind".

She quotes here the introduction to the dictionary itself, which presumably contains quite a few examples of such words. Unfortunately, off hand I can't think of any examples myself, and I have not been able to consult the dictionary, which does not seem to be freely available online.

So I would like to ask: are there examples of German words that look like French ones (e.g. contain a French root or a suffix) but have no analogues in French (and in particular, are not loanwords)?

https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/roma.1995.46.issue-1/roja-1995-0132/roja-1995-0132.xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A word like that would be called a "Scheingallizismus". "Gallizismen" are loan words from French, like for example "Anglizismen" are loan words from English. Words that *seem* to originate from the respective language but actually don't (anymore) are called "Schein-" (roughly meaning "pseudo"), in our case "Scheinanglizismus" or "Scheingallizismus".

An often cited Scheinanglizismus is the German "Handy" for "cell phone". But [according to Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheingallizismus) there are also Scheingallizsmen. The article doesn't seem to have much proof, but some of the examples noted there seem reasonable enough to me:

- Blamage (would be something like « honte » in French)
- Friseur ( « coiffeur » )
- Takelage ( « gréement » )
- Staffage ( « décoration » )
- Gardine ( « rideau » )

It varies to what degree the (pseudo-) French pronunciation is still used in German. With "Blamage", for example, the final "e" may or may not be pronounced. But I don't remember ever hearing *Gardin'* ;)

Comment: It should be noted that it's a bit open to interpretation whether you consider various of these words Scheingallizismen (assuming the entire word is French) or rather something like nouns built by appending a French rather than a German noun ending to a German word.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I don't want to start a lengthy discussion, but wouldn't "nouns built by appending a French rather than a German noun ending to a German word" be Scheingallizismen as well? The French noun ending would make the words "look French" even though they're not, which is basically the point of the category.

Comment: It's true the German root is often not as readily recognizable in Scheingallizsmen as in Scheinanglizismen. I presume, however, that the neologism "Beleidigtness" does not count as a "Scheinanglizismus" despite the English ending attached to the German word. IMO, the same applies with respect to French endings attached to German word/word parts.

Answer (score 5):

The possibly most prominent pseudo-French word in German is *Friseur* (hairdresser, the actual French word being *coiffeur*). However, according to the German Wikipedia [Friseur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friseur#Bezeichnungen) the word did exist in French, but was never very popular and is nowadays extinct.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best word in such a list has be ***Politesse***
meaning:

> kommunale Angestellte, die die Einhaltung der Parkvorschriften überwacht

Describing a female traffic warden.

But looking into etymology we get only the French:

> [**Etymologie**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Politesse)
>   Politesse1 f. ‘Höflichkeit, Galanterie’, Übernahme (17. Jh.) von gleichbed. frz. politesse, zu frz. poli Adj. ‘geglättet, poliert, kultiviert, höflich’, polir Vb. ‘glänzend machen’ (s. ↗polieren).

In other words: looks like French, is also a word in French, but has no direct connection to French, other than being of diametrically opposite content.

Comment: "diametrically opposite content" - you made my day! :-)